# Is rpm2cpio installed by default on CentOS

Tags: centos, rpm

I am writing some scripts for CentOS. Is **rpm2cpio** installed by default on CentOS?
I read somewhere **rpm2cpio** comes with rpm package, but I am not sure. I couldn't figure out from RMP project website.

For CentOS 5 and 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rpm package is installed by default on CentOS and RHEL systems, and rpm2cpio is included in the rpm package as shown here:

```
$  rpm -ql rpm | grep -P 'rpm2cpio$'
/usr/bin/rpm2cpio
```

Therefore, yes, rpm2cpio is included in CentOS 5 and 6.